# Rails activerecord includes. How to access the included columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My User model `has_many :event_patrons` and EventPatron `belongs_to :user`.  I would like to slap together the user with one specific event patron with something like this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `event_patrons` ON `event_patrons`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE `event_patrons`.`event_id` = 1
```

So in rails I tried this:

```
User.all(:joins => :event_patrons, 
         :conditions => {:event_patrons => {:event_id => 1}})
```

But that gives me `SELECT users.*` instead of `SELECT *`:

```
SELECT `users`* FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `event_patrons` ON `event_patrons`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE `event_patrons`.`event_id` = 1
```

I then tried to switch the `:joins` with `:include` and got a whole jumbled mess that still returned me only the columns in `User` and none from `EventPatron`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake a completion:

In rails 3 you could actually get away with only one query, but they recommend using joins as well: 
User.includes(:event_patrons).where("event_patrons.event_id", 1)

Source: [Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

I was confused with joins and includes in the beginning as well, but there is a big difference:

- include basically does an eager loading on the association. This is useful when you're going to do something like this:

  ```
  @users.each do |user|
    user.event_patrons.first.event_id
  end
  ```

  If you have 100 users then you'll you've just generated 100 extra queries (the 1+N problem).
- sometimes you need to specify a condition on the association (like in your case) and this is where joins are useful, but don't over-abuse it, or you'll run into the cartesian product overload problem.

  A great article on all this: can be found here, might be for rails 2.1 but still applicable for Rails 3 as well: http://akitaonrails.com/2008/05/25/rolling-with-rails-2-1-the-first-full-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Rails does that on purpose. You should use the query like this:

```
User.all(:joins => :event_patrons, 
         :conditions => {:event_patrons => {:event_id => 1}}
         :include => :event_patrons)
```

That will generate 2 queries. One for the users:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `event_patrons` ON `event_patrons`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE `event_patrons`.`event_id` = 1
```

And one for the associated event_patrons:

```
SELECT `event_patrons`.* FROM `event_patrons` WHERE `event_patrons`.`id` IN (1,2,3...)
```

You could do what you want, by specifying the :select option, but I wouldn't advise this, because then it doesn't construct the event_patrons models, it leaves the data in the users model.